# Set up event handlers with jQuery in ajax response

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a home.php page that has a button to invoke an ajax call to replace the contents of an element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
         $ajax(...).done(function(response) { $("#home-cabinet").html(response) });
    });
});
```

There are some HTML elements in the ajax response that I would also like to bind some event handlers. But the problem is I don't know the content of response, so I cannot stick the jQuery element selector code inside .done().

It makes more sense if I can let the response set up the handlers itself. How can I do that?

Comment: If you just send some javascript back in the response, jquery will parse it automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the response data

```
<input type="button" id="newElement" />
...
...
<script>
    $('#newElement').on('something', function(){});
</script>
```

Just note that the DOM ready event doesn't fire on ajax requests, so make sure the `<script>` is written after the element.

> But the problem is I don't know the content of response

You should know what you're going to get, it's your domain you're requesting... anyway the above should work just fine.

Comment: AH... the key is to put `<script>` **AFTER** the element. As for the content of the response, yes i do know it. It was a hypothetical case e.g. if different people were working on different parts etc. plus I thought it made more sense for the response to customise itself.